# Apache Cache with multiple CacheRoots

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, cache

I configured Apache with a CacheRoot directory for each of my domains / virtual hosts:

```
<VirtualHost>
ServerName domain1.tld
...
CacheRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.tld/httpdocs/cache
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost>
ServerName domain2.tld
...
CacheRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain2.tld/httpdocs/cache
...
</VirtualHost>
```

I have this up and running for quite a while and so fare it's working pretty well except that I have to empty out the cache manually every so often because htcacheclean does't know of the different directories.

Now I would like to setup htcacheclean to watch over the cache directories but as fare as I understand the manual, I can only set it to one cache directory. I would like to do something like this but that doesn't work:

```
<VirtualHost>
ServerName domain1.tld
...
CacheRoot /var/www/vhosts/domain1.tld/httpdocs/cache
    htcacheclean -n -t -p/var/www/vhosts/domain1.tld/httpdocs/cache -l1024M
...
</VirtualHost>
```

Is it even right to have multiple cache directorys or should I work with just one cache directory for all of the domains?

Answer (score 0):

`htcacheclean` is not an apache directive (-: so it can't go in your conf files. You have to run it "[manually or in daemon mode](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/htcacheclean.html)", per the documentation. HTH.